# Java - Как правильно организовать хранение пары: команда -> строки_результата

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Добрый день.

Требуется хранить пары данных — список комманд и результат их выполнения.

Результат выполнения может быть в виде нескольких строк; соответственно, нужен массив.
Команды могут быть не уникальными.

Напрашивается конструкция `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>`, но в этой коллекции ключ должен быть уникальным.
Мне не подходит.

Подскажите, как можно реализовать.

Comment: Попробуйте `json` :)

Comment: Не хотелось бы работать с файлами. Все таки хочется простой классики :) Наверняка  можно реализовать массивами или коллекциями, только опыта нет.

Comment: Я немного не понял, что вы имеете ввиду под **уникальный**? Типа могут быть разные ключи?

Comment: Ключи не могут быть  разными, поэтому мне коллекция не подходит. У меня комманды могут повторяться. Фактически это пары  комманда->массив строк

Comment: Ну, попробуйте HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>. Во внешнем ArrayList - результаты различных команд с одинаковым именем, а во внутреннем - ответ на конкретную команду. Просто, как вы иначе собираетесь идентифицировать команду, если по одному названию их может быть несколько.

Comment: думал как-то очередь прикрутить, потом :) что-то я уже совсем запутался

Comment: Вроде нашел то, что нужно. 
Но не пойму почему в этом Map не соблюдается уникальность ключа, мне это не нужно, для понимания хочется понять:
<pre><code>
    List<Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
    pairList.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, ArrayList<String>>("Red", result1));
    pairList.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, ArrayList<String>>("Red", result2));
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entr : pairList) {
            System.out.println("Button: " + entr.getKey() + "    Label: " + entr.getValue());
        }
</code></pre>

Answer (score 2):

Какие getKey? Что за getValue? Кто (включая автора через пару недель) этот бред разберёт?

```
public class CommandResultPair {
    private String command;
    private List<String> result;
    ...
    // get, set, construct...
}

...

List<CommandResultPair> crps = new ArrayList<>();
while (...) {
    String commnad = ...
    List<String> result = ...
    crps.add(new CommandResultPair(command, result));
}

...

for(CommandResultPair crp : crps) {
    String command = crp.getCommand();
    List<String> result = crp.getResult();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Естественно он не проверяет никакую уникальность. Уникальность проверяет Map. Использовать его конечно можно в данном случае. Но ООП для того и есть, чтобы оперировать объектами, похожими на настоящие. Вам же нужны команды и результаты, а не ключи и ассоциированные с ними значения.

Comment: Ясно.Спс.  Я думал такие простые пары уже built-in в Java. Оказывается нет  и насколько я понимаю, лучше создавать свои классы.  Реализовал через классы, так как советовали. Мой пример в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал отдельный класс:

```
public class CommandResultPair {
private final String  command;
private final ArrayList<String> result;


public CommandResultPair(String command, ArrayList<String> result) {
    this.command = command;
    this.result = result;
}

public String getCommand() { return command; }
public ArrayList<String> getResult() { return result; }

@Override
public int hashCode() { return command.hashCode() ^ result.hashCode(); }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (!(o instanceof CommandResultPair)) return false;
    CommandResultPair pairo = (CommandResultPair) o;
    return this.command.equals(pairo.getCommand()) &&
            this.result.equals(pairo.getResult());
}}
```

Так проверяю:

```
public class ExampleCommanResultPair {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String str1 = "command1";
    String str2 = "command2";

    ArrayList<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    result1.add("result1_line1");
    result1.add("result1_line2");

    ArrayList<String> result2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    result2.add("result2_line1");
    result2.add("result2_line2");

    CommandResultPair cmd1 = new CommandResultPair(str1,result1);
    CommandResultPair cmd2 = new CommandResultPair(str2,result2);


    ArrayList <CommandResultPair> commandArray = new ArrayList<>();

    commandArray.add(cmd1);
    commandArray.add(cmd2);
    commandArray.add(new CommandResultPair("command3",result1));

    for (CommandResultPair cmdItr : commandArray){

        System.out.println("Result for command \"" + cmdItr.getCommand() + "\"");
        cmdItr.getResult().forEach((resultItr) -> {System.out.println( resultItr   );}     );


    }

}}
```

Вывод:

```
    Result for command "command1"
result1_line1
result1_line2
Result for command "command2"
result2_line1
result2_line2
Result for command "command3"
result1_line1
result1_line2
```

Вроде бы то, что нужно.

Comment: Рекомендация использовать List вместо ArrayList (кроме new ArrayList естественно:)

Comment: Т.е. вместо ArrayList<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(); использовать List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>();   ?  Можете объяснить почему, я заметил это в Вашем совете ранее, но не смог понять  эту конструкцию и ее смысл.

Comment: Тут кажется такой вопрос(почему List правильнее ArrayList) уже поднимался